# Error while waiting for protractor to sync with the page on catching alert during refresh

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am getting this error while I refresh the page and catch the alert:

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined. 
>   This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because
>   your test involves client-side navgation, which can interfere with
>   Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details".

Please see the code used below:

```
browser.refresh().catch(function(){
browser.switchTo().alert().then(function(alert){
        alert.accept();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Alert isn't an Angular Alert, in which case you should tell Angular you're not testing an Angular Application anymore.

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Then proceed with the rest of your code after

```
browser.refresh().catch(function(){
browser.switchTo().alert().then(function(alert){
        alert.accept();
});
```

If you want it to behave again in an Angular way (in terms of waiting for HTTPS requests etc) then you will need to re-enable it after accepting your alert

```
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
browser.waitForAngular();
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```